# Resize text inside a button

Tags: css, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to resize the button text when the window change size, but i don't know how to do that. I'm using NetBeans, JavaFX and Scene Builder.
Look at the images:
The button grows larger but the font size remains the same.
[image: from here]
[image: to here]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setFont` method.
For example

```
button.setFont(Font.font(40));
```

to change text style

```
button.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,20));
```

Comment: no, when i drag the window and the button change size, the text inside the button should change too! but remain the same size!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scaleX property and scaleY property.

Assuming you are resizing with an outerPane.

```
final double origHeight  = outerPane.getPrefHeight();
final double origWidth = outerPane.getPrefWidth();
button.scaleXProperty().bind(outerPane.widthProperty().divide(origWidth));
button.scaleYProperty().bind(outerPane.heightProperty().divide(origHeight));
```

You could paste the code different places depending on how you setup your application.

I tested by pasting this into FXMLDocumentController, replacing the empty initialze() that was already there:

```
@FXML
private Button button;

@FXML
private AnchorPane outerPane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    final double origHeight = outerPane.getPrefHeight();
    final double origWidth = outerPane.getPrefWidth();
    button.scaleXProperty().bind(outerPane.widthProperty().divide(origWidth));
    button.scaleYProperty().bind(outerPane.heightProperty().divide(origHeight));
}
```

Save and compile, then reopen SceneBuilder and set the `fx:id` in the Code tab on the right for the pane that gets resized to `outerPane` and the Button to `button`.

Comment: this is not the solution i need, i have to readapt the button font when i expend the window by draggin and i don't figure out how to do that. thank you!

Comment: Changing the scale of the button changes the text in the button as well.

Comment: your code doesn't work very well, this is what i see:
[![from][1]][1]
[![to][2]][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gmeqe.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/We5cB.png

Comment: there is a method to grow up the font while i'm dragging the window in the css? or only by code?

Comment: If you want multiple buttons to scale together, put them in the same innerPane and scale the pane instead of the buttons individually.  I don't know what options are available in css.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93080/discussion-between-luca-alberto-and-willshackleford).

Answer (score 0):

You should bind a value to Font Size and apply it using styleProperty(), like this:

```
DoubleProperty fontSize22 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(22);
fontSize22.bind(homeButton.widthProperty().add(homeButton.heightProperty()).divide(10));
homeButton.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize22.asString(), "px;"));
```